# Duplicate with no answer (II)

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

A user has posted twice the same question with different accounts:

[Karaoke/instrumental version of HotCha song](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/8411/karaoke-instrumental-version-of-hotcha-song)

[Is there any similar backgroud music for this lyrics?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/8412/is-there-any-similar-backgroud-music-for-this-lyrics)

I can't mark one as dupe of the other because the first one has no answers.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Bebs! I went ahead and deleted the first one from the account the user says he can no longer access.